# how to execute executable file with arguments using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

powershell version 2.2 . 
what im trying to do is login to remote server with psexec then stop spooler service and then disable spooler from automatic startup after reboots. Here is what i want to execute

`c:\remotetool>Psexec.exe \\10.10.10.10 -u demouser1  -p "secretpassword" -h  net stop spooler && sc config "spooler" start= disabled`

The error i get is

```
&& is not valid statement separator in this version
```

When i execute *psexec* individually like below it works but i want to execute them on single connection

```
c:\remotetool>Psexec.exe \\10.10.10.10 -u demouser1  -p "secretpassword" -h  net stop spooler

c:\remotetool>Psexec.exe \\10.10.10.10 -u demouser1  -p "secretpassword" -h  sc config "spooler" start= disabled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try

`` cmd /c Psexec.exe \\10.10.10.10 -u demouser1  -p "secretpassword" -h  net stop spooler `&`& sc config "spooler" start= disabled ``

Comment: is that backtick alongside `&` ?

Comment: @satch_boogie yes